# linux CLI screenshot without X

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

is there an easy FOSS way to get a screenshot of a curses-based command line GUI when X isn't installed?

What if the powers-that-be say I can't remote login? (I'm working on it ha)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25063/capturing-area-of-the-screen-without-a-desktop-environment

Answer (score 5):

SSH to the server and run the curses-based command; it should translate properly to curses "graphics", depending on how your terminal client's emulation is configured. Screenshot using your desktop OS's utility.

At least, that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the screen program, and pressing ctrl-a h will write the screen to a file 'hardcopy.n'.

Answer (score 2):

[scrot](http://freshmeat.net/projects/scrot/) is a cli based screenshot tool which i've used before. Its a little quirky (it'll take a screenshot of the system i'm sshed in from) but might be ideal for your needs

Comment: scrot works great, instantly, just `scrot` from xterm or `M-! scrot` in emacs. Only - it requires X to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on a virtual terminal (e.g. [Ctrl]-Alt-F1), you can, from another terminal, type:

```
sudo cat /dev/vcs1 > screenshot_file
```

or

```
sudo cat /dev/vcsa1 > screenshot_file
```

but the results probably won't be satisfactory.

Comment: Why not, you just have to edit it somewhat! (This can be automatized.) A screenshot from a CLI application should be in text, that's so brilliant no wonder I didn't think of it. Best answer!

Comment: Any idea how to automate the post-processing for /dev/vcsa1? For /dev/vcs1  something like `sudo cat /dev/vcs1|sed -E 's/.{240}/&\n/g' works for me (where 240 is the $COLUMNS of that terminal), but then color information is lost.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Joe mentioned you can also use a virtual machine to get screen shots of things that you can't do any other way such as the installer.

If getting the output of a session including all commands and output command as text would be better then have a look at the `script` command.  And in some situations something like `pastebinit` may be appropriate.

Although I'm not sure how script deals with a curses based app.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this on old serial terminals by takeing a photo of the termial screen. This is simple and works with no modifications to the terminal at all.

Comment: yeah, this is a reasonable backup, i just need to fill out a few papers and wait a week for a photographer to come ;)

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be a video loopback. In theory, you could use a Video4Linux device then capture its output with a v4l capture program.